# Redshift select while keeping row order

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using [ROW_NUMBER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html) to assign a unique row id to Redshift table rows like:

```
with 
    testset (rowid) as (
    select '1' union
    select '2' union
    select '3' union
    select '4' union
    select '5' union
    select '6' union
    select '7' union
    select '8' union
    select '9' union
    select '10'
),
testset_sorted as (
select
   row_number() over (),
   rowid
   from testset
   order by row_number
)
select * from testset_sorted order by row_number
```

but the resulting table has assigned `row_number` cols not in the same order of col `rowid`:

```
row_number,rowid
1,7
2,6
3,3
4,10
5,5
6,8
7,9
8,2
9,4
10,1
```

so the ordering is not respected:

```
select
   row_number() over (),
   rowid
   from testset
)
```

I get

```
row_number,rowid
1,4
2,2
3,5
4,8
5,9
6,10
7,7
8,1
9,6
10,3
```

While I would expect to have

```
row_number,rowid
1,1
2,2
3,3
4,4
5,5
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row_number() window function just needs to know what order you want things in with an "order by" clause.

```
with 
    testset (rowid) as (
    select '1' union
    select '2' union
    select '3' union
    select '4' union
    select '5' union
    select '6' union
    select '7' union
    select '8' union
    select '9' union
    select '10'
),
testset_sorted as (
select
   row_number() over (order by rowid),
   rowid
   from testset
   order by row_number
)
select * from testset_sorted order by row_number;
```

For more info see - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: Okay thank you, this mean that without the clause “order by” within the row_humber, the ordering will be left to the query engine, not necessarily matching the starting order.

Comment: Correct.  Also, since Redshift is a cluster there really isn't a "starting order".  Each slice has its set of rows and while these may be sorted locally, when the full results are constructed the ordering of the slice results will be based on which slice responded fastest.